# How to call dragscroll function manually after pageload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below code for dragscroll which runs automatically when page load.

But I want to call this function manually because I'm uppending the html using DOM element.

I have tried with window.factory as well as window.reset but it is not working for me.

My Javascript module file:

```js
   (function (root, factory) {
     if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
       define(['exports'], factory);
     } else if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
       factory(exports);
     } else {
       factory((root.dragscroll = {}));
     }
   }(this, function (exports) {
 var _window = window;
 var _document = document;
 var mousemove = 'mousemove';
 var mouseup = 'mouseup';
 var mousedown = 'mousedown';
 var EventListener = 'EventListener';
 var addEventListener = 'add'+EventListener;
 var removeEventListener = 'remove'+EventListener;
 var newScrollX, newScrollY;

 var dragged = [];
 var reset = function(i, el) {
  for (i = 0; i < dragged.length;)
   {
      <some code>
  }

  // cloning into array since HTMLCollection is updated dynamically
  dragged = [].slice.call(_document.getElementsByClassName('dragscroll'));
  for (i = 0; i < dragged.length;)
   {
     <some code>
     }, 0
    );

    _window[addEventListener](
     mouseup, cont.mu = function() {pushed = 0;}, 0
    );

    _window[addEventListener](
     mousemove,
     cont.mm = function(e) {
      if (pushed) {
       (scroller = el.scroller||el).scrollLeft -=
        newScrollX = (- lastClientX + (lastClientX=e.clientX));
       scroller.scrollTop -=
        newScrollY = (- lastClientY + (lastClientY=e.clientY));
       if (el == _document.body) {
        (scroller = _document.documentElement).scrollLeft -= newScrollX;
        scroller.scrollTop -= newScrollY;
       }
      }
     }, 0
    );
    })(dragged[i++]);
  }
 }


 if (_document.readyState == 'complete') {
  reset();
 } else {
  _window[addEventListener]('load', reset, 0);
 }

 exports.reset = reset;
}));
   })
```

I want to call above function manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try with

> window.dragscroll.reset();

this will call your reset function manually.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a standard JavaScript module that exports a `reset()` method. Depending on your environment you can load this module, e.g with CommonJS it would be

```js
const module = require('name/path/of_your_module_file');
```

and then to call it when the DOM load is complete with jQuery:

```js
$(() => {
    module.reset();
});
```